# Change the colour of a table view cell once user has clicked on it even when app is refreshed

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

When a user clicks on a cell in the table view it changes colour but when they refresh the app (e.g. log out and log back in or swipe up on their iPhone) the cell changes back to the original colour - is it possible to make it so when the user refreshes the app, the cells that the user has clicked on remains the changed colour to show it has been opened?

UPDATE:

Code in the view controller

```
extension NotificationViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return notifications.count
}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NotificationTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! NotificationTableViewCell
        let notification = notifications[indexPath.row]
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        cell.notification = notification
        cell.user = user
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245, green: 245, blue: 245)
        return cell
     }
}
```

code in the UITableViewCell

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    let cellBackground = UIView()
    cellBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245, green: 245, blue: 245)
    UITableViewCell.appearance().selectedBackgroundView = cellBackground
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Snippet of JSON firebase structure:

```
 "notification" : {
    "CjeP35ceAQZJuUPhm7U1eF3Yq4F3" : {
      "-La5XJZV059J-fcbH4Px" : {
        "from" : "Gmg1ojNoBiedFPRNSL4sBZz2gSx2",
        "objectId" : "-La5XJYuWm6dLfGnte2h",
        "timestamp" : 1552740338,
      },
      "-La6KbtcG7VIIk7JsBvT" : {
        "from" : "Gmg1ojNoBiedFPRNSL4sBZz2gSx2",
        "objectId" : "-La6KbtbAAAPjeo98dGe",
        "timestamp" : 1552753786,
      },
     "FoFQDAGGX9hntBiBdXYCBHd8yas2" : {
       "-La6Kb4DyACBRihJf4c1" : {
       "from" : "Gmg1ojNoBiedFPRNSL4sBZz2gSx2",
       "objectId" : "-La6Kb42zWtwcAVlubK7",
       "timestamp" : 1552753783,
      },
```

Comment: Of course it's possible. You have to save the *selected* state in the data model and update it in `cellForRow`.

Comment: By the data model, do you mean i would have to save it in firebase for example (which is what i'm using to store data)? Sorry i'm new to this so sorry if it's a stupid question

Comment: The *data model* is the type of the array which represents the data source of the table view

Comment: Would it be possible to do it using the storyboard?

Comment: No. The storyboard is the *view*, you have to maintain the *model* in the *controller*.

Comment: I've tried to update the selected state and update it in the cell for row (updated code above) - would you mind telling me if there is something missing (the selected state works but not when i refresh and the cellForRow makes it not work)? Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: You were correct above, when you said that you need to save it in something like Firebase; Any information or state that needs to persist between executions of your app needs to be stored somewhere.  You can't rely on in-memory storage since that will be reset when you restart your app.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense, I have added a snippet of my firebase structure as an update - would you mind explaining how I could save this when a user clicks on the cell in order to show the colour change whenever the app restarts? Thanks for your help

Comment: you can add a flag let say `isSelected` to your model and check the state of selection with that flag if it was true then change the color of the cell based on its own dataSource

Comment: Thanks for your response - just to be clear, would I check the state of selection under the setSelected function (and reference the isSelected flag there) and then the colour under cellForRow (in code i've attached above) or shall I create a new function for the change of colour? Just trying to understand how it would work so I really appreciate the help :)